# How to fix work manager class which is not working fine?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I write code for work manager but it show nothing when it runs and also give no error.

I search A lot and read all questions about work manager but don't understand problem.

```
   OneTimeWorkRequest uploadWorkRequest = new 
   OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(UploadWorker.class)
   .build();
   WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(uploadWorkRequest);
```

Here is worker class:

```
   public class UploadWorker  extends Worker {
   Context context;


   @Override
    public Result doWork() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"es",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new 
    AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    alertDialog.setTitle("Do You Want to Delete This Record");
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false)
            .setMessage("Click yes to delete")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new 
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("No", new 
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog1=alertDialog.create();
    alertDialog1.show();

    return Result.SUCCESS;
   }


   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misusing WorkManager; you should not use it for what you are attempting. Try moving code inside your `doWork` method to a fragment or activity.

Comment: I just follow documentation

Comment: OneTimeWorkRequest uploadWorkRequest = new 
   OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(UploadWorker.class)
   .build();
   WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(uploadWorkRequest);    I write this code in my mainActivity

Comment: Don't use WorkManager for this; it is designed to facilitate background execution of tasks. You are trying to use it to interact directly with the UI which is not an appropriate use of WorkManager. Try moving the code in your `doWork` method to a method that you create in your activity and then invoking that method.

Comment: ok thank you so much Now I understand your point but please tell me which type of work I can do in doWork method? Give me  3 to  4 examples so that I better understand advantage of this process

Comment: Sir please tell me one thing? Is it possible to create dialog using worker class